# Is this solvable as an ODE or PDE? What function of unknowns will be left over?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a differential equation that looks like it could be interpreted either as a PDE or ODE.

Let's say we have a function in several variables, $f(y,b,x).$ If you integrate $\int f_y dy$ you obtain the original function $f$, plus some unknwon $\phi(b,x).$

The equation I have is

$$\frac{x-f}{y} = f_y,$$ where $f_y$ is the derivative of $f(y,b,x)$ with respect to $y.$ Can I solve this as though it were an ODE in terms of the variable $y,$ or do I need the characteristic method interpreting this as a PDE? What left over function of unknowns do I have?

Comment: I'd say you can safely treat it as a (non-homogeneous) ODE. The equation doesn't know that $x$ and $b$ are "variables" and not simply "parameters".

Comment: Okay, so we can solve it as an ODE then. When you solve an ODE, you generally get a family of constants in the general case, like a coefficient $c_1.$ Is $c_1$ in this case some $\phi(b,x)$?

Comment: The coefficient $c_1$ is generally fixed by imposing some initial or boundary conditions. If you have reasons to believe that these extra parameters $x,b$ may play a role on this initial condition, then in a sense yes, $c_1=c_1(b,x)$.